# How to pass additional convert options to paperclip on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :square => "100%", :large => "100%" },
    :convert_options => {
      :square => "-auto-orient -geometry 70X70#",
      :large => "-auto-orient -geometry X300" },
    :storage  => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
    :bucket => 'mybucket'

  validates_attachment_size :photo,
    :less_than => 5.megabyte

end
```

Works great on local machine, but gives me an error on Heroku: `There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream.20143`
The thing is I want to auto-orient photos before resizing, so they resized properly.

The only working variant now(thanks to jonnii) is resizing without auto-orient:

```
...
as_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :square => "70X70#", :large => "X300" },
        :storage  => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
        :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
        :bucket => 'mybucket'
...
```

How to pass additional convert options to paperclip on Heroku?

**UPD**

I discover, the trouble in "-auto-orient" option. It seems like this option is broken in version of ImageMagick used by Heroku. I created custom paperclip image processor inherited from paperclip's standard thumbnail:

```
module Paperclip

  class Ao < Thumbnail

    def transformation_command
      super + " -auto-orient"
    end

   end
end
```

It works perfect on local machine, but fails on Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the sizes I use.  They all work fine on heroku:

```
SIZES = {
  :original => "640x480>",
  :thumb => "150x150#",
  :mini => "60x60#",
  :micro => "30x30#"
}
```

Make sure your gem version of **paperclip** is the same as heroku's. You can specify the specific gem version in your `.gems` file and in your `environment.rb` to make sure they line up.

I'm not sure exactly why your `convert_options` are causing problems, but if I remember correctly paperclip uses ImageScience directly and your chosen options might be incompatible with the read only heroku file system.

If this is critical and you need an answer right now I'd raise a support ticket on heroku.  If you get a response make sure you post it back here!